# zlib uncompression error in java

Tags: java, zlib

I have a java code which uncompresses (zlib compression) bytes received in the socket connection ... the system is able to uncompress when the Server PC is 32 bit and uses zlib.dll but the same code throws DataFormatException when the Server is changed to 64bit processor & OS - and the Server system uses zlib64.dll to compress.

(This is what the Server-side System Company is saying to us)

According to Server-Side System - it will check whether the Server processor & OS is 32bit or 64bit and then compress the data packets accordingly and send it.
My Code:

```
 Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
              inflater.setInput(message);
              ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(compHeader.MsgLen);
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
              while (!inflater.finished()) {  
            int count = 0;  
                  try {
                      count = inflater.inflate(buffer); // ERROR LINE - THROWS DATAFORMATEXCEPTION of java.util.zip java package
                  } catch (DataFormatException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(BroadCastManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
               }  
              try {  
                  outputStream.close();
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(BroadCastManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
```

Can you provide a code alternate which can handle both - 32 bit and 64 bit ?? or say what could be the actual reason of this problem ?

Comment: I believe the reason is not the architecture. From the [zlib FAQ](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_faq.html#faq25) `Will zlib work on a big-endian or little-endian architecture, and can I exchange compressed data between them? - Yes and yes.`  Can you provide a dummy data example (e.g. compressed "hello world" or something).

Comment: update - according to the server side team - the error is due to inability of handling the new heartbeat byte packets ... Sad to say that this problem is yet not resolved by us due a lot complication at our end as well as at the server side team.

Comment: You could anyway dump the data you receive and investigate it yourself. Without further knowing what your server team mean, it sound a bit strange that a heartbeat package should lead to data corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the data are not compressed with zlib but rather with gzip?

Take following as example

```
echo "hello zlib" > /tmp/in
gzip /tmp/in
# will result in /tmp/in.gz
```

If you try to decompress it like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
byte[] message = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/in.gz"));
Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
inflater.setInput(message);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.out.println("read input as zlib");
try {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, inflater.inflate(buffer));
    Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/out.txt"), outputStream.toByteArray(),
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (DataFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("ex = " + ex);
}
```

... an exception `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check` is thrown.

If you decompress it as gzip like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
Path gzipPath = Paths.get("/tmp/in.gz");
System.out.println("read input as gzip");
try (GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(gzipPath))){
    int read = gzip.read(buffer);
    buffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, read);
    Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/gzip.inflated"), buffer,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

... the file `/tmp/gzip.inflated` will be created.